# Why does this jUnit test keep failing?

Tags: java, junit

When I run the jUnit test it keeps saying Number format exception the string does not have a proper length of a card number, any Idea's whats wrong with the code and how I maybe be able to fix this? I have posted the test, code and trace below:

Test:

```
 @Test
public void testToString() {
    assertEquals("Branch [name=Poole, address=12 Swanage Road, phoneNumber=01202123457, bankManager=Sarah Jane]", branch2.toString());
}
```

Trace:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: The string "377659710738349" does not have the proper length of a card number
at prog2.as1.CardNumber.<init>(CardNumber.java:19)
at prog2.as1.BankCard.getNextCardNumber(BankCard.java:68)
at prog2.as1.BankCard.<init>(BankCard.java:54)
at prog2.as1.CurrentAccount.<init>(CurrentAccount.java:95)
at prog2.as1.test.BankCommon.setUp(BankCommon.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Card Number:

```
public class CardNumber extends FilteredString {

/**
 * Create a new instance. After removal of spaces, dots and tabs there must
 * be 16 digits left for a valid card number.
 * 
 * @param origString The input string.
 */
public CardNumber(final String origString) {
    super(origString);
    if (toString().length() != 16) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("The string \"" + origString + "\" does not have the proper length of a card number");
    }
}


/**
 * Filter out certain characters. Filters tabs, spaces and periods, Accepts
 * digits.
 * 
 * @param c {@inheritDoc}
 * @param number {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
protected int filterCodePoint(final int c, final int pos, final String number) {
    switch (c) {
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            // Add to phone number
            return c;
        case ' ':
        case '\t':
        case '.':
            // Ignore
            return 0;
        default:
            throw new NumberFormatException("The string \"" + number + "\" does not represent a valid card number");
    }
}

 }
```

Bank Card:

```
public class BankCard {

private static long lastNumber;

static {
    Random r = new Random();
    do {
        lastNumber = r.nextLong() % 10000000000000000l;
    } while (lastNumber < 0l);
}

/**
 * An enumeration of the types of bank cards.
 *
 * @author Paul de Vrieze
 */
public static enum CardType {
    /** A cash card. */
    CashCard,
    /** A debit card. */
    DebitCard,
    /** A credit card. */
    CreditCard;
}

private CardNumber cardNumber;

private Calendar expiry;

private CardType kind;

/**
 * Create a new bank card of the specified type.
 *
 * @param type The type of card.
 */
public BankCard(final CardType type) {
    kind = type;
    cardNumber = getNextCardNumber();
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    expiry = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 3, now.get(Calendar.MONTH), 1);
}

/**
 * Get a new 16 digit card number, randomly increased from the last one.
 *
 * @return A random card number.
 */
private static CardNumber getNextCardNumber() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    lastNumber = (lastNumber + 1 + rand.nextInt(100000)) % 1000000000000000l;
    Formatter f = new Formatter();
    CardNumber result = new CardNumber(f.format("%015d", Long.valueOf(lastNumber)).toString());
    f.close();
    return result;
}

/**
 * Get the expiry date of the card.
 *
 * @return A calendar with the expiry date.
 */
public Calendar getExpiry() {
    return expiry;
}


/**
 * Set the expiry date of the card.
 *
 * @param expiry The new expiry date.
 */
public void setExpiry(final Calendar expiry) {
    this.expiry = expiry;
}


/**
 * Return the type of the card.
 *
 * @return The type.
 */
public CardType getKind() {
    return kind;
}


/**
 * Set the type of the card.
 *
 * @param kind The new type of the card.
 */
public void setKind(final CardType kind) {
    this.kind = kind;
}

/**
 * Get the number of the card.
 *
 * @return The card number.
 */
public CardNumber getCardNumber() {
    return cardNumber;
}

/**
 * Set the number of the card.
 *
 * @param cardNumber The new card number.
 */
public void setCardNumber(final CardNumber cardNumber) {
    this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return cardNumber + (new Formatter()).format(" exp: %1$tm/%1$ty", expiry).toString();
}

    }
```

Current Account:

```
public class CurrentAccount extends Account {

private BankCard debitCard;

/**
 * Get the debit card for this account.
 * 
 * @return The debit card.
 */
public BankCard getDebitCard() {
    return debitCard;
}

/**
 * Set the debit card for this account.
 * 
 * @param debitCard The debit card. The card type must be
 *            {@link CardType#DebitCard}.
 */
public void setDebitCard(final BankCard debitCard) {
    if (debitCard.getKind() != BankCard.CardType.DebitCard) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The given card is not a debit card");
    }
    this.debitCard = debitCard;
}

/**
 * Get the credit card for this account.
 * 
 * @return The credit card.
 */
public BankCard getCreditCard() {
    return creditCard;
}


/**
 * Set the credit card for this account.
 * 
 * @param creditCard The credit card. The card type must be
 *            {@link CardType#CreditCard}.
 */
public void setCreditCard(final BankCard creditCard) {
    if (creditCard.getKind() != BankCard.CardType.CreditCard) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The given card is not a credit card");
    }
    this.creditCard = creditCard;
}

private BankCard creditCard;

private BigDecimal overdraftLimit;

/**
 * Create a new account with initial zero balance.
 * 
 * @param customer The customer owning the account. This account will be
 *            added to the customer automatically.
 * @param accountNumber The account number.
 * @param overdraftLimit The overdraft limit on the account.
 */
public CurrentAccount(final Customer customer, final AccountNumber accountNumber, final BigDecimal overdraftLimit) {
    super(customer, accountNumber);
    this.overdraftLimit = overdraftLimit;
    setDebitCard(new BankCard(BankCard.CardType.DebitCard));
    setCreditCard(new BankCard(BankCard.CardType.CreditCard));
}

/**
 * Create a new account with initialized with a given balance.
 * 
 * @param customer The customer owning the account. This account will be
 *            added to the customer automatically.
 * @param accountNumber The account number.
 * @param balance The initial balance of the account.
 * @param overdraftLimit The overdraft limit on the account.
 */
public CurrentAccount(final Customer customer, final AccountNumber accountNumber, final BigDecimal balance, final BigDecimal overdraftLimit) {
    super(customer, accountNumber, balance);
    this.overdraftLimit = overdraftLimit;
    setDebitCard(new BankCard(BankCard.CardType.DebitCard));
    setCreditCard(new BankCard(BankCard.CardType.CreditCard));
}

/**
 * Get the overdraft limit for the account.
 * 
 * @see prog2.as1.Account#getOverdraftLimit()
 */
@Override
public BigDecimal getOverdraftLimit() {
    return overdraftLimit;
}

/**
 * Set the overdraft limit of the account.
 * 
 * @param overdraftLimit The new limit.
 */
public void setOverdraftLimit(final BigDecimal overdraftLimit) {
    this.overdraftLimit = overdraftLimit;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = super.toString();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(s.length() + 50);
    result.append(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1)).append(", debitcard: [").append(debitCard).append(']');
    result.append(", creditcard: [").append(creditCard).append("])");
    return result.toString();
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public String getAccountName() {
    return "Current Account";
}


    }
```

Bank Common:

```
package prog2.as1.test;

 import java.math.BigDecimal;
 import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

 import org.junit.Before;

 import prog2.as1.AccountNumber;
 import prog2.as1.Address;
 import prog2.as1.Bank;
 import prog2.as1.Branch;
 import prog2.as1.CurrentAccount;
 import prog2.as1.Customer;
 import prog2.as1.EmploymentStatus;
 import prog2.as1.HighInterestSavingsAccount;
 import prog2.as1.ISASavingsAccount;
 import prog2.as1.PhoneNumber;
 import prog2.as1.StandardSavingsAccount;


 @SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
 public class BankCommon {

protected Bank bank;

protected Branch branch1;

protected Branch branch2;

protected Branch branch3;

protected Customer customer1;

protected Customer customer2;

protected Customer manager3;

protected Customer manager2;

protected Customer manager1;

public BankCommon() {
    super();
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    manager1 = new Customer("Gordon", "Gecko", new GregorianCalendar(1951, 5, 23), EmploymentStatus.Permanent);
    branch1 = new Branch("Winton", new Address("6", "Bournemouth Road", "BH4 1AA", "Bournemouth", "Dorset", Address.UK), new PhoneNumber("01202 123456"), manager1);
    manager2 = new Customer("Sarah", "Jane", new GregorianCalendar(1952, 2, 29), EmploymentStatus.SelfEmployed);
    branch2 = new Branch("Poole", new Address("12", "Swanage Road", "BH12 5XY", "Poole", "Dorset", Address.UK), new PhoneNumber("01202 123457"), manager2);
    manager3 = new Customer("John", "Person", new GregorianCalendar(1961, 11, 5), EmploymentStatus.Temporary);
    branch3 = new Branch("Bournemouth", new Address("6", "Winton Road", "BH1 1AA", "Bournemouth", "Dorset", Address.UK), new PhoneNumber("01202 123458"), manager3);
    bank = new Bank("Northern Rock", branch1, branch2, branch3);


    customer1 = new Customer("John", "Doe", new GregorianCalendar(1970, 1, 1), EmploymentStatus.Unemployed);
    customer1.addAccount(new CurrentAccount(customer1, AccountNumber.getNextAccountNumber(), BigDecimal.valueOf(100), BigDecimal.valueOf(500)));
    customer1.addAccount(new ISASavingsAccount(customer1, AccountNumber.getNextAccountNumber(), BigDecimal.valueOf(1000)));
    branch1.getCustomers().add(customer1);

    manager3.addAccount(new CurrentAccount(manager3, AccountNumber.getNextAccountNumber(), BigDecimal.valueOf(10000)));
    manager3.addAccount(new HighInterestSavingsAccount(manager3, AccountNumber.getNextAccountNumber(), BigDecimal.valueOf(20000)));
    branch3.getCustomers().add(manager3);

    customer2 = new Customer("Jane", "Doe", new GregorianCalendar(1971, 1, 1), EmploymentStatus.Temporary);
    customer2.addAccount(new CurrentAccount(customer2, AccountNumber.getNextAccountNumber(), BigDecimal.valueOf(100), BigDecimal.valueOf(600)));
    customer2.addAccount(new HighInterestSavingsAccount(customer2, AccountNumber.getNextAccountNumber(), BigDecimal.valueOf(1000)));
    branch1.getCustomers().add(customer2);

    manager2.addAccount(new CurrentAccount(manager2, AccountNumber.getNextAccountNumber(), BigDecimal.valueOf(200)));
    manager2.addAccount(new ISASavingsAccount(manager2, AccountNumber.getNextAccountNumber(), BigDecimal.valueOf(6000)));
    branch2.getCustomers().add(manager2);

    manager1.addAccount(new CurrentAccount(manager1, AccountNumber.getNextAccountNumber(), BigDecimal.valueOf(500)));
    manager1.addAccount(new StandardSavingsAccount(manager1, AccountNumber.getNextAccountNumber(), BigDecimal.valueOf(5000)));
    branch1.getCustomers().add(manager1);

}

}
```

Comment: The testcase keeps failing because the code under test is throwing the exception.  It has nothing to do with the string comparison in the test. The code under test never completes normally.

Comment: Use a debugger to figure out what's happening?

Comment: You already asked this question once.

Comment: You'll have to debug your code.  Whatever's calling the Card constructor is passing a 15-char string to it, which is tripping your exception.  You have coded a bug, and you need to look over your code to fix it.  This is not a problem you should expect other people to solve for you.  This is what programming is.

Comment: @user2971783 You read the stacktrace, and try to understand what it says. In this case, it spells it out: "The string "377659710738349" does not have the proper length of a card number". And it says that this exception is thrown at CardNumber.java line 19. Go to that line and realize the code expects a credit card number to be 16 digits. You're generating numbers of 15 digits.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a homework question that has no re-use value for others.

Comment: Come to the labs for help with your questions. This does not belong on stackoverflow. You don't learn anything from this.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it is because the generated String for the CardNumber is longer or shorter than 16 characters:

```
if (toString().length() != 16) {
    throw new NumberFormatException("The string \"" + origString + "\" does not have the proper length of a card number");
}
```